# Making sense of some code

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make sense of some code and hoping you can give me some input.

```
def not_death(foo):
    next = foo - 200000.0
    bar = max(0, next * 0.04)
    next = foo - 140388.0
    bar += max(0, next * 0.03)
    next = foo - 90563.0
    bar += max(0, next * 0.055)
    next = foo - 45282.0
    bar += max(0, next * 0.055) 
    bar += foo * 0.15 
    return bar
```

The code refers to a function to calculate taxes payable. Your input would be appreciated in helping me make sense of the code and describe what's going on.

Comment: From what I see there is no tax upto ` 200000.0`. There is 4% tax for anything above ` 200000.0`, 3% tax for anything above  200000.0+140388.0 etc..

Answer (score 0):

It's applying marginal tax rates, much like the U.S. federal income tax. It might actually *be* U.S. federal income tax rates for some year or another; I haven't checked.

```
next = foo - 200000.0
bar = max(0, next * 0.04)
```

applies a 4% (`0.04`) rate to anything above 200000 dollars/whatevers.

```
next = foo - 140388.0
bar += max(0, next * 0.03)
```

applies a 3% (`0.03`) rate to anything above 140388 dollars/whatevers. And so on. It adds those up as it goes along (the `bar += ...` statements), so you get higher rates on the highest amounts and lower rates on lower amounts. It's a so-called "progressive" tax: the first dollar/whatever gets taxed the least, while the last dollar/whatever gets taxed the most.

That said, this is *horrible* code. It uses `foo`, `bar`, and `next` as variable names, for crying out loud. You should be deeply suspicious of all code written by whoever wrote this, IMHO.